# checking url and taking parameters from it to form element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Here i have a form which has initialValue(which works) but when user edits the form and changes value for example from 'cat' to 'dog' and goes to second page and come back to this same page, then i see there is initialValue as cat and not dog, so how to take it from url(here i have 'dog')? it would be something like if there is 'animal=dog' then initial value is 'dog' if not then it is cat.   In console i'm getting 'animal=dog&human=&pickUpPhone=+358945618' my code:

```js
  const { t } = useTranslation();
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];
console.log(query);
```

```html
<Form.Item
        label={t("info.animal")}
        name="animal"
        initialValue={props.animals?.name || ""}
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSearchParams and extract the values like so:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const animal = urlParams.get("animal") || "Cat";

console.log(animal);
```

Variable "animal" will either be the value that comes from the "animal" parameter otherwise it will default to "Cat"

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: it is not giving me the 'dog' why?

Comment: Please refer the documentation